# Fixed header won't obey page width

Tags: html, css

I'm building the framework for a responsive site that has a fixed header and 25px padding on both right & left sides of the page. I'm not encountering any issue with the padding or width on the content, but the fixed header runs off the right side of the browser when the display is too small. I'd like the header to obey the same rules and design as the rest of the page, and always show a 25px padding unless the display is narrower than my min-width.

Any help would be appreciated. This seems rather simple, but I'm pulling my hair out.

**CSS:**

```
#main {
    padding: 0 0px 0 25px;
    min-width: 725px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#page {
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 725px;
    position: relative;
}

ul#header-nav {
    margin: 33px 0px 0 0px;
    list-style:none;
    width:500px;
    font-family: "ss-bol", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul#header-nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color:#000000;
    float:left;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline;
}

#container {
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#header-main {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 -25px 0 0px;
}

#header-frame {
z-index: 10;
    background-color: #c9dcb1;
    float: right;
}

#header-box {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 725px;
    padding-left: -25px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin:0px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #c9dcb1;
z-index: 11;
}

#content {
padding-top: 100px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #75efe8;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <!-- BeginHeader -->
    <div id="page" class="clearfix heed">
        <div id="header-main">
        <div id="header-box">
            <div id="header-frame">
                <ul id="header-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">NEW</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WINE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LOOKBOOK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="content">
            TEST CONTENT TEXT
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: if you want a fully responsive site, percentage widths are better, but anyway, put this in a jsfiddle so we can see whats going on - http://jsfiddle.net/9ZXx6/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simon, I took the basics of your approach and expanded upon it to get what I needed.

Here's the final CSS:

```
#header-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#header .inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

ul#header-nav {
    margin: 58px -20px 0 0px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 500px;
    font-family: "ss-bol", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul#header-nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="right">
        <ul id="header-nav">
        <li><a href="#">NEW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WINE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LOOKBOOK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

padding, margin and border are added to the with of an element. So, when your display is to small, by telling `max-width: 1000px`, you imply 1050px because of the padding.

The easy solution is to replace `width: 100%` by this left and right set as 0, and center your inner content.

```
<div id="header-box">
    <div class="inner">header</div>
</div>

#header-box {
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 725px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#header-box .inner {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm affraid this did not do that trick. Setting 'left' and 'right' to 0 just anchored the header to the left most side of the display, as well as disrupted the vertical layout. Now the header is overlaying the content.

Comment: I've edited the code with minimal explanation of how you can adjust your header. Of course, this won't change the way CSS box model works; explained at the beginning of the answer (so don't set a fixed width + padding on `.inner`)

Comment: Thanks for the work Simon, but I'm sad to say that these variations are just rearranging the issues at hand.

Comment: It looks like my issues are coming down to a single line of code. the position:fixed; is what throws it off. Is there a way that I can attribute position:fixed; to the outer div, but have the inner rely on attributes exactly like the content which are responding perfectly?

Comment: Then, can you please create a jsfiddle or a dabblet example so we see more precisely what are your needs ?